# Unable to properly convert the Pseudo code to c# code

Tags: c#, linq

I have basically tried to covert the following code to c# but not sure if it is correct. Could somebody please correct me. As you can see the condition if (collateralSum < 0) repeats twice. Its there in the pseudocode but doesnt look right in c#

Pseducode

[image]

c# code

```
 private static string GetDirection(IEnumerable<NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition> positions)
        {
            string direction = string.Empty;
            decimal derivativeSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct != "Cash Account")
                                             .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);
            decimal collateralSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account")
                                             .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);

            if (!positions.Any())
            {
                return LongShortIsinType.None;
              
            }

            if (derivativeSum == 0 && collateralSum >= 0)
            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralOut;
            }

            if (collateralSum < 0)
            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralIn;
            }

            if (collateralSum / derivativeSum  < -1 && collateralSum >= 0)

            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralOut;
            }
            if (collateralSum < 0)
            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralIn;
            }

            if (collateralSum / derivativeSum >= -1 && derivativeSum + collateralSum >= 0)

            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.Long;
            }

            if (derivativeSum + collateralSum < 0)
            {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.Short;
            }

            return direction;

        }
```

Comment: Your pseudocode shows nested `if` conditions, why not use that in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My translation of the pseudo-code, similar but leaving out the redundant testing (sorry about the reformatting, my editor does that automatically):

```
private static string GetDirection(IEnumerable<NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition> positions) {
    decimal derivativeSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct != "Cash Account")
                                     .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);
    decimal collateralSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account")
                                     .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);

    if (!positions.Any())
        return LongShortIsinType.None;

    string direction;
    if (derivativeSum == 0) {
        if (collateralSum >= 0) {
            direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralOut;
        }
        else {
            direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralIn;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (collateralSum / derivativeSum < -1) {
            if (collateralSum >= 0) {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralOut;
            }
            else {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralIn;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (derivativeSum + collateralSum >= 0) {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.Long;
            }
            else {
                direction = LongShortIsinType.Short;
            }
        }
    }

    return direction;
}
```

NOTE: I would probably re-write the whole thing as below:

```
private static string GetDirection2(IEnumerable<NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition> positions) {
    decimal derivativeSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct != "Cash Account")
                                     .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);
    decimal collateralSum = positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account")
                                     .Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount);

    string direction;
    if (!positions.Any())
        direction = LongShortIsinType.None;
    else if (derivativeSum == 0 || collateralSum / derivativeSum < -1)
        direction = (collateralSum >= 0) ? LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralOut : LongShortIsinType.ExtraCollateralIn;
    else
        direction = (derivativeSum + collateralSum >= 0) ? LongShortIsinType.Long : LongShortIsinType.Short;

    return direction;
}
```